# Using OpenCV for IP camera

Tags: java, opencv, camera

I'm just a student who is given the project to do people counting using IP camera without buying anything. I have done research for the past 3 days and seems that OpenCV is the only free program but I'm unsure if it is able to do people counting.

Is there any links that teaches how to set up OpenCV? I found one at http://robocv.blogspot.it/2012/01/using-your-ip-camera-with-opencv.html but I'm not sure if I should configure it using the method stated in the link.

Your help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use opencv in java by using native opencv C code. Or you can use JavaCV.

yes people counting is possible using open cv. You have to use body detection and object tracking.